# convert a row to columns in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I change the format of the following  dataframe

```
 Time       Aug-19    Sep-19    ...     Jul-20     Aug-20    Sep-20     
 Products        
 Book        60.9      82.7742  ...    77.2258     0.0000     0.0     0.0000
 TV          70.9      87.7742  ...    77.2258     0.0000     0.0     0.0000
```

to this

```
 Products     date      Value          
 Book        Aug-19     60.9   
 Book        Jul-20     0.0000                
 TV          Sep-20     0.0000
```

Comment: try `df.stack()`

Answer (score 0):

try using `stack`:

```
df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'date', 0: 'Value'})
```

---

```
    Products    date    Value
1   Book    Aug-19  82.7742
2   Book    Sep-19  77.2258
3   Book    Jul-20  0.0000
4   Book    Aug-20  0.0000
5   Book    Sep-20  0.0000
6   TV      Time    70.9000
7   TV      Aug-19  87.7742
8   TV      Sep-19  77.2258
9   TV      Jul-20  0.0000
10  TV      Aug-20  0.0000
11  TV      Sep-20  0.0000
```